# Are my definitions of cotangent space, differential and differential forms and coboundary operator correct?

Tags: definition, analytic-geometry

> - Define the *cotangent space* $T_a^*\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the *differential* of a dunction $f$ at the point $a, df \in T_a^*\mathbb{R}^n$. Write down the explicit formula for the deffertial $df$ in terms of partial derivatives.
> - Define a *differential form* $\omega$ on an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.
> - Define the *coboundary operator* $D: \Omega^k(U) \rightarrow \Omega^{k+1}(U)$.

My definitions are:

- Let $M$ be a smooth manifold & $a$ a point in $M$. Then $T_a(M)$ is defined as the tangent space at $a$. The cotangent space is then the dual space of $T_a(M)$, at $a$, i.e $T_a^*(M)$. The elemems in $T_a^*(M)$ are linear functions on $T_a(M)$.

The differential, $df$, of a function $f$ at $a$ is an element of the duals space $T_a^*(\mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by the following notation

$$df({\underline{v}}) = {\underline{v}}(f).$$

The formula is

$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1, \cdots , \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dx_n.$$

- Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset. A $k$ form $\omega \in \Omega^k(U)$ is an expression

$$\omega = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \omega_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_1, \cdots x_n)dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}.$$

- The definition of the coboundary operator is

$$d\left( \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \omega_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_1, \cdots x_n)dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k} \right)$$

$$ = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} \{d\omega_{i_1, \cdots i_k}(x_1, \cdots x_n)\} \wedge dx_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}.$$

Are these correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of this question. Did you just make these definitions up or did you find them somewhere? You can just check in any number of books or online notes whether or not these are correct. Why ask us to do it? You should have plus instead of comma in the formula for $df$.

Comment: @Matt I'm working through a load of theory questions and these were some that came up. I looked on line but none of the definitions matched these exactly and these are the ones that I have written down so I wanted to check if my ones were correct but written differently or if they were wrong.